# How to save data from API in device Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my application a lot of data received from the api, how to save data on device when app starts, and take this data from device and take data from the device without making an api call every time.
I can show on the example of my futureBuilder, every time when I go to UserPage, my user data is loaded, how can I save it?

```
late Future<User> userFuture = getUser();
  static Future<User> getUser() async {
    var url = '${Constants.API_URL_DOMAIN}action=user_profile&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}';
    print(Constants.USER_TOKEN);
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return User.fromJson(body['data']);
  }

              FutureBuilder<User>(
                future: userFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return buildProfileShimmer();
                    // Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final user = snapshot.data!;
                    return buildUser(user);
                  } else {
                    return Text("No widget to build");
                  }
                },
              )
```

Comment: Depends on your data: you can use [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) (for small amount of data) or for larger amount of data use a local database, like [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) or [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or others

Comment: which database is more convenient to use sqlite or hive?

Comment: hive has better performance when compared with other NoSql storage. 1. https://blog.logrocket.com/comparing-hive-other-flutter-app-database-options/, 2. https://objectbox.io/flutter-databases-sqflite-hive-objectbox-and-moor/

Comment: Objectbox is one of the best dbs performance wise.